# NULL values in database on create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activemodel

When i clicked to submit, the parameters is shown with all the data, however, when i save it, it shows as:

```
 SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `billings` (`birth`, `city`, `country`, `created_at`, `gender`, `ictype`, `idno`, `marital`, `name`, `national`, `phone`, `postcode`, `race`, `reference_id`, `shipping_address`, `state`, `street1`, `title`, `updated_at`, `uptime`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, '2014-08-28 02:55:19', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2014-08-28 02:55:19', NULL, 1)


class Billing < ActiveRecord::Base
#  attr_accessible :user_id
  attr_accessible :title, :birth, :ictype, :idno, :race, :gender, :national, :street1, :postcode, :city, :state, :marital, :shipping_address

  belongs_to :user
end

Class ShoppingCartsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @billing = Billing.new(params[:billing])
        @billing = current_user.build_billing
        @billing.save
    end

end
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
def create
#    @billing = Billing.new(params[:billing])
    @billing = current_user.build_billing(params[:billing])
    @billing.save
end
```